# R dataframe with mixed type returning integer instead of string

Tags: r

I have a table with differeent types in it. one of the column is of type string, other are integer.
I want to retrieve the content row by row, but I don't know how to tell R a column is a string I want to retieve as a string. Here is a minimal running example:

```
# create small toy dataset
a=c("label1", 3, 56, "foo")
b=c("label2", 1, 2, "bar")
d=as.data.frame(rbind(a,b)) # in my original code I have a data.frame

# retrieve a row
e = d[1,]
# take the first column: all is OK
e[1]
# the unexpected stuff:
type(e[1]) # I expected "character" but obtain "list"
unlist(e)  # I expected something like "label1"
as.character(e[1]) # I expected something like "label1"
```

Can anyone tell me what happen and how should I correct it?

Comment: When you do `e[1]` you are selecting a `data.frame` with one column. try doing `class(e[1])`. When you do `e[,1]` you are selecting only the column. The reason `typeof(e[1])` return a `list` is because `data.frame` is essentially a list. Try reading `?data.frame`

Comment: Also your vectors `a` and `b` will be all characters. You can't store mixed classes in a simple vector.  Also, you should really use `class()` to determine the behaviors of an object.